# ASP.NET MVC 3 remove /Home

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 internet application in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, and I have noticed that with this default template, the path `localhost:port/Home` shows the same content as `localhost:port/`

Is there a way to remove the `/Home`? I would only like `localhost:port/` to be the landing page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both urls work because that's how the default route has been defined in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This means that all of `/`, `/Home` and `/Home/Index` will land to the `HomeController/Index` action. So in fact when you are request `/` it is the exact same action being executed.

You can modify it like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Of course by doing this the only controller and action you will ever be able to run in your application will be the HomeController and Index action. No other action or controller will be ever accessible as you don't provide any means in the url to specify them. So I would leave the default routes as is because they allow to handle 99% of the cases unless you have some specific requirements.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing (`{id}` as a route). Yet I think you still can register other routes (`{controller}/{action}/{id}` for instance) and only your home controller will never show up in a url for action Index. `Url.Action("Index", "Home", {id = 1})` will just return /1, while `Url.Action("About", "Home")` will still return /Home/About.

Comment: @Major Byte, I showed this only as an example to provide some explanation about routing, not as something that should be used.

Answer (score 3):

The other guys are correct. However they dont really tell you a way around it. One way to get better control of the routes is as follows

Do something like below in the Register routes method

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        var controllers = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.Navigate(_ => _.BaseType).Any(_ => _ == typeof(Controller)));
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            var actions = controller.GetMethods().Where(m => m.HasAttribute<RouteAttribute>()).Select(m => new { Method = m, Attribute = m.GetAttribute<RouteAttribute>() }).ToArray();
            foreach (var action in actions.OrderBy(m => m.Attribute.Path.Count(c => c == '{')))
                routes.MapRoute(string.Format("{0}.{1}", controller.Name, action.Method.Name), action.Attribute.Path.TrimStart('/'), new { controller = controller.Name.Replace("Controller", ""), action = action.Method.Name });
        }
```

and then decorate your controller methods with a route attribute that defines exactly what the route should be. You have to make the route attribute yourself, it cna be pretty simple just an attribute with a string parameter . In this fashion you can set any controller method to have any route you like.

Comment: +1 For keeing route registration from being a 400 page document.